# Does RDBMS guarantee row level atomicity?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

When not using transactions, is that possible a record is half-modified(not all fields requested are modified or only part of a BLOB modified)?
Does it depend on different database like SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: A transaction is guaranteed to complete entirely, or fail and rollback (barring some things like deadlock, etc.). Can you give some context to this question?

Comment: This is to do with [ACID compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). InnoDB and SQLite should do it. MyISAM, being really brittle, is a *probably* but no guarantees as corruption problems can occur.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But My question is "when not using transaction". I think you can configure your DB so that a single SQL sentence is not an transaction.

Comment: Then I think the answer is yes, and consider this example.  One process has partially updated a record, when at that exact moment another process does a select and reads that record.  Now the second process has read partially updated inconsistent data.  This is why the concept of row lock exists in most RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are not using explicit transactions, both SQLite and MySQL use autocommit mode, i.e., they will wrap an implicit transaction around every SQL statement:
[SQLite transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)
[MySQL transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Even when you reduce transaction isolation with "read uncommitted", the database will not allow you to read partially updated values.